# Completely OO C++ SQL Wrapper?

Tags: c++, sql

So I'm looking for a SQL wrapper for C++ that completely hides any textual SQL statements.  I just can't seem to find any, I'm wondering why all the wrappers out there seem at some point to want you to write a textual SQL statement such as:

```
SELECT * FROM stock WHERE item = 'Hotdog Buns'
```

here's MySQL++ for example:

```
mysqlpp::Query query = conn.query("select * from stock where item = 'Hotdog Buns'");
```

The most obvious way to do this for me is to create a class that contains properties (columns) with each instance of that class being a row.  So to do the above query I would do something like:

```
// Class defined something like this...
class stock_item : public sql::row
{
public:

   stock_item() : m_name( NULL ), m_amount( 0 ) {};
   ~stock_item() {};

   // Statically define the table
   static void CreateTable( void )
   {
      // Some C++ reflective mechanism
      sql::column( "name",   char[50] );
      sql::column( "amount", u32 );
   }

private:

   const char* m_name;
   u32         m_amount;
}

// Then a table defined like this
sql::table<stock_item> stock;

// Query function defined something like this...
stock GetHotDogBuns( const stock& shopStock )
{
   stock hotDogBuns = shopStock.Select( stock_item::Name(), "Hotdog Buns" );
   return hotDogBuns;
}
```

Now I'm no SQL expert and I haven't spent very long thinking about the above code but it just seems quite a logical way to deal with a database if your from a C++ background rather than having to be a database expert.  What are the problems with this kind of approach?

Is there an open source library that allows you access to a database in a similar fashion?

*EDIT* The reason why I would like something like this is so that C++ programmers using our code don't have to learn SQL syntax and to provide a much more natural environment for them to code in.  I've seen something like this in the SilverStripe CMS written in php.

Comment: SQL is a skill all database programmers should have.

Comment: I'm working with a team of programmers that aren't database programmers and have more important skills to master for their jobs without the need for that kind of added complication.  The database is just useful to have in this scenario especially if access is encapsulated away from them by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [hiberlite](http://code.google.com/p/hiberlite/) and [litesql](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/litesql/).

Answer (score 4):

RogueWave used to (maybe still do) have C++ database access library like this - using it was sheer hell. SQL is a very powerful language, and encapsulating all of it in C++ classes is a very difficult proposition. Also, you haven't made clear, to me at least, what your motivation for doing this is.

Comment: Yes thats also the info I'm after: why was it sheer hell?  I would probably only require a few of the more common features of the SQL language not every nook and cranny.  I've added the motivation for why I would like this to my question.

Comment: +1 The "sheer hell" part is also my experience

Comment: It was hell because to use it, you had to learn a very large and not well-designed C++ library, which at the end of the day took maybe a hundred line of C++ to do what you could do simply in a couple of lines of SQL. It didn't leverage C++ skills, it just made sure you couldn't use your SQL ones effectively. It also had a get-out Exec( sql ) function which after a few tries using the class library, everyone  ended up using.

Comment: object oriented and relational data models do not have a 1:1 mapping of concepts, there are fundamental differences.  Resultantly, any attempt to model one in the other will require a certain amount of kludginess.  The more advanced the feature set that is exposed, the more painful the mapping will be to use.

Comment: @Greg D: So what are the fundamental differences or where can I find out what specifically they are?

Comment: Look up information about designing or implementing an ORM, object-relational model.  That ought to be a good place to start your research.

Answer (score 1):

Quince is an open source C++ library that saves you having to use SQL syntax or SQL types, but still gives approx the same expressiveness as SQL. Currently supports PostgreSQL and sqlite only, but new backends can always be added. See quince-lib.com. (Full disclosure: I wrote it.)

Answer (score 0):

I have written my own library of Fields and Records.

The Field class has methods such as:

```
virtual std::string         get_sql_creation_text(void) const = 0;
virtual std::string         get_sql_insert_data(void) const = 0;
virtual std::string         get_sql_where_clause_equals(void) const = 0;
virtual std::string         get_value_as_string(void) const = 0;
```

My Record class is a container of pointers to strings.
I build a SQL statements by iterating over the fields using the above methods.

So one of my queries looks like:

```
12:37:41: Selecting rows for iterating using:
SELECT  *
 FROM  Ing_Quantified
LEFT JOIN Ing_Processing USING (ID_Processing)
LEFT JOIN Ing_Process_Degrees USING (ID_Process_Degree)
LEFT JOIN Ing_Process_Methods USING (ID_Process_Method)
LEFT JOIN Ingredients USING (ID_Ingredient)
LEFT JOIN Ing_Titles USING (ID_Title)
LEFT JOIN Ing_Varieties USING (ID_Variety)
LEFT JOIN Ing_Categories USING (ID_Category)
LEFT JOIN Ing_Container_Sizes USING (ID_Container_Size)
LEFT JOIN Ing_Container_Types USING (ID_Container_Type)
LEFT JOIN Meas_Fundamentals USING (ID_Measurements)
LEFT JOIN Meas_Systems USING (ID_System)
LEFT JOIN Meas_Types USING (ID_Types)

WHERE (ID_Recipe = 1);
```

All this done while treating the records and fields as generic.  The Fields return their names, which helps in creating WHERE clauses and in the USING clauses above.

I was using wxWidgets wxDbTable, but it doesn't easily support generic fields and records.